# How to update my UI values in android?

Tags: java, android, json, mobile-development

I am new to android and wondering if anyone can help me by pointing me or giving me a code example (preferably) on how to update my UI values (simple text view value) from a response from my server (JSON object).

my j son is

`{num : 1, val: 22}`.

Thank you

Comment: can you share your code??

Comment: @sumit added background task , thank you

Comment: then inside  onpostUpdate method you can change your values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is another method called `onPostUpdate()` ,in which you can pass your response from `doInbackground()` and parse and set response into `TextView`.

Use below method to parse your `json` resopnse.

```
 private void parseResponse(String responseString) {
        try {
            //{num : 1, vol: 22}
            Object object = new JSONTokener(responseString).nextValue();
            if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
                String num = jsonObject.optString("num");
                String vol = jsonObject.optString("vol");

                textView.setText("num="+num+" "+"vol="+vol);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the doinbackground task is not on my java class for the activity how would i pass that value from the 'data manager class' (doinbackground task here) to the 'room 1' class which is set with the XML/UI activity? Thank you!

Comment: for this you need to create an Interface and that should be implemented by Activity  and there reference should be passed into `DataManager` Class in which your `doInBackground()` exist but form `onPostUpdate()` method of `AsynTask` Class .